# Performance tuning with MiniProfiler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance

I am working on website performance and need a little bit of help determining a slow spot. Below is a snapshot of a typical request to the home page. Obviously I can speed up the SQL a bit, but where can I look to see what took the first step `(http://168.62.16.83:80)` 168ms?

Does anyone have any advice, or blog post that explains what goes on behind the scenes, and tips on optimizing it? Or is this just the time it took to download all the static content?

[image]

Comment: I got that sql to sub 50ms, but I'm still stumped on the first step. I am in RELEASE mode, and debug=false in config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most effective way to find stuff like this is use a traditional profiler like ants, dotTrace or the built in one. ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers))

As to where the time, it is possible you have an expensive spot in `Application_BeginRequest` or during authentication.

Comment: For the record the apparent slowness was due to the Azure cache. I had my website deployed in west coast region, and the cache in the north central. Whoops!. Moving them to the same data center cut off 150ms off that request. It also made the sql call another 20ms faster. woot!